# Weird discrepancy in size between fdisk and df

Tags: partition, fdisk, df

`fdisk` reports the following info about a partition

```
     Device: /dev/sda1
       Boot: *
      Start: 2048
        End: 209715166
    Sectors: 209713119
  Cylinders: 443369
       Size: 100G
         Id: 83
       Type: Linux
Start-C/H/S: 0/32/33
  End-C/H/S: 766/42/11
      Attrs: 80
```

While `df` gives me this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.1G  8.4M  3.1G   1% /run
/dev/sda1        20G   19G     0 100% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.1G     0  3.1G   0% /run/user/1000
```

How would I go about recuperating the 80G for use?

Update `fdisk -l /dev/sda`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd958ae29

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 209715166 209713119  100G 83 Linux
```

**Fixed using `resize2fs /dev/sda1`**

Comment: Run the command `fdisk -l /dev/sda` and add the output to your question.

Comment: You created a 20GB filesystem on a 100GB partition. If this is an ext3 or ext4 filesystem, try `resize2fs /dev/sda1`. If it's XFS, use `xfs_growfs`.